# Spring Boot - Web Application Context Bean Scope

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket, javabeans

I have a class `A` as a bean.

```
public class A
{
   // constructors
   // properties
   // getters and setters
}
```

Spring boot configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AConfig{
    @Bean
    @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public A getA() {
        return new A();
    }   
}
```

I am working right now with WebSocket and I am trying to get a new class A instance for some specific WebSocket channels, let's say if I am working with WebSocket `id:1` then I will have the instance of A (some address) for that WebSocket, and for the WebSocket `id:2` I will have another instance of A (some other address), and I can have it across application. How can I achieve that? In this case, I guess I have to send some ID to the server to identify the spring bean I am looking for.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't simply use the WebSocket scope (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes)?

Comment: @Smutje, I can't find anything specific about how to implement this together with Websocket. Any help on that?

Comment: please confirm my understanding: You want bean of Class A in other class say Class WebSocketTest, and in every instance of class WebSocketTest there is a separate bean of class A with different different state( different address) .

Comment: What do you mean "how to implement this together with Websocket"? Have you checked the link and tried it out?

Comment: @Jitendra, yes! For instance the scope `scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_APPLICATION` works fine in different instances, but it creates a single bean across the whole application. Now I want when I receive a new WebSocket connection to build at that time a new bean of a class let's say `A` that I can access it from different clients.

Comment: @Smutje, I can't find more of this documentation, like when it is created? How should I connect it with Websocket?

Comment: "WebSocket-scoped beans when first accessed are stored in the WebSocket session attributes. The same instance of the bean is then returned whenever that bean is accessed during the entire WebSocket session.

We can also say that it exhibits singleton behavior but limited to a WebSocket session only." - you DID read the link I posted?

Comment: @Smutje apparently I have to create the Websocket client connection through spring and not Javascript to have access to this class and at the moment I can create the bean?

Comment: What does this has to do with the way the WebSocket client works? This scope is for beans used in the WebSocket server part.

Comment: I did read that part of the documentation, but it is not clear for me when do I have to initialize this bean? For the WebSocket configuration I have only the config class where I specify the endpoints. So where should be my `@Autowired private A a;` ?

Comment: If you would need to initialize the bean yourself, what would the scope be useful for? Simply access it how you would access other beans - in this case in the beans that you use to process the WebSocket requests in.

Comment: @Smutje true. Now I have it @Autowired at some controller and I get the following error: `Scope 'websocket' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound SimpAttributes found. Your code is probably not processing a client message and executing in message-handling methods invoked by the SimpAnnotationMethodMessageHandler?`

Comment: "at some controller" - how about the class that handles your WebSocket requests?

Comment: @Smutje, yes it is working there! Is this because of the `@MessageMapping` injection that it understands that it has to do with sockets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206729/discussion-between-flowcyan-and-smutje).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Instead of Autowired we should use Constructor arguments to make it loosely coupled  **

```
class MessageSocketDemo {

private A a;

public MessageSocketDemo(A a) {
    this.a = a;
}

public MessageSocketDemo() {
    a = new A("address");
}
```

}

```
class A {
String address;

public A(String add) {
    address = add;
}
```

}

**So when you create object of MessageSocketDemo you create object of A every time new.
Or make the Scope of A as prototype or request which will create it new every time it is asked, and a lookup method to create instance of A**